# 16×16や25×25の数独を計算量を抑えて作成したい

Tags: php, アルゴリズム

下記のように数独を作るプログラムをかきました。

1. 升目を初期化する（例 1～9までの場合は9×9の升目を初期化する）
2. 左上から幅優先探索で値をランダムに入れていく
3. ランダムで入れていき、（行・列・ブロック内でかぶって）入れられる値がなくなったら、かぶった２つの升目を初期化して再度実行

9×9では問題なく（遅いと感じることなく）作成できたのですが、
16×16では途端に重くなり、無限ループのようになり処理が終わりません。

上記3の、
升目に入れられる値がないときに、かぶった２つの升目を初期化して再度実行、
が永遠繰り返されるように見受けられたので、
かぶった値をメモして、再度実行の際にはそれを省いて実行しようとしたのですが、
たいしたかわらずでした。（ソースは汚くなったのでここでは省略）

別の観点での実装方法やソース中の改善方法等、教えてほしいです。

```
public function make()
{
  // 数独のブロック数
  $blkNum = 9;

  // マスを初期化
  for ($i = 0; $i < $blkNum; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $blkNum; $j++) {
      $d[$i][$j] = -1;
    }
  }

  // startを左上に設定
  $sx = 0;
  $sy = 0;
  $d[$sx][$sy] = rand(1, $blkNum); // set start to init

  // move vector
  $dx = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0];
  $dy = [0, 0, 1, 0, -1];

  $queue = [[$sx, $sy]];
  // [0] : x
  // [1] : y

  while ($queue) {
    $now = array_shift($queue);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { // vector movement num
      // nx, ny : after move mass
      $nx = $now[0] + $dx[$i];
      $ny = $now[1] + $dy[$i];

      if ($nx >= 0 && $nx < $blkNum && $ny >= 0 && $ny < $blkNum && isset($d[$nx][$ny]) && $d[$nx][$ny] == -1) {
        // 挿入する値を計算する
        // ※やっていることはランダムで値を渡し、行・列・ブロックで重複しなければその値を採用する
        $calc = $this->__put($d, $nx, $ny, range(1, $blkNum));
        if ($calc['result'] === true) { // 正常に値がとれたときは値をいれ、pushする
          $d[$nx][$ny] = $calc['value'];
          array_push($queue, [$nx, $ny]);
        } else { // 正常に値がとれなかったとき
          // 重なっている部分を初期化し、
          // queueにつみpushする
          $d[$nx][$ny] = -1;
          $d[$calc['err_x']][$calc['err_y']] = -1;
          array_push($queue, [$calc['err_x'], $calc['err_y']]);
          array_push($queue, [$nx, $ny]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
* __put パラメータに入る値を取得する
*
*/
private function __put($d, $nx, $ny, $param) 
{
  // 配列をランダムにしてqueueでとってい く
  shuffle($param);
  while($param) {
    $p = array_shift($param);
    // 値をチェックする（行・列・ブロック内での重複チェッ ク）
    $check = $this->__check($d, $nx, $ny, $p);
    if ($check['result'] === true) { // チェックok -> return
      return ['result' => true, 'value' => $p];
    } else { // チェックNG -> paramを減らしてregression
      if ($param) {
        return $this->__put($d, $nx, $ny, $param);
      } else { // paramがないと き
        // 最後まで値が入らなかったので、重複チェックで引っかかったx,yをreturnする
        return ['result' => false, 'value' => $p, 'err_x' => $check['x'], 'err_y' => $check['y']];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

あたりをつけて、簡単な検証しかしてませんので参考までに…

手順は

1. 基本形の生成
2. シャッフルする

です。

1. は、

python ですが、以下のコードで
水平方向昇順なシンプルな数独が生成できます。

```
def create(num=3):
    num2 = num * num
    g = [[0]*num2 for i in range(num2)]

    for y in range(num2):
        yy = (y * num) % num2 + int(y / num)
        for x in range(num2):
            g[x][yy] = (num2 - y + x) % num2 + 1
```

9x9(num=3)だと

`a b c d e f g h i
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1`

って感じです。(a-zは 2で使うので付与してます)

2. シャッフル

1.で生成したものを数独を壊さないようにシャッフルします。

下記条件を満たせば数独は壊れません。

- a列 と、b(or c)列の入れ変え
- a,b,c列と d,e,f(or g,h,i)列の入れ変え

  これは、行でも成り立ちますので、計4つのシャッフルを十分な回数実行すれば、
  ランダムな数独になると思います。

Comment: なるほど、最初に基本形をつくってシャッフルをするんですね。
たしかにこれなら升目が多くなっても速いですね。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 行列シャッフルだけだと思ったよりパターン数がないっぽいので、

「数字のシャッフル」 も含めると改善すると思います。

Comment: そうですね、基本形の生成をする際に、数字をシャッフルしたものを使えば、100×100でも速度、中身ともに十分よいものができました。

Answer (score 3):

最初に全ての空きマスに全ての数字のフラグを立てます。
16×16ならば1〜16の数字を各空きマスにセットするということです。

そして、次の4ステップを繰り返します。

1. 数字が確定している各マスについて、そのマスの縦1列にある空きマスから確定している数字のフラグを取り除く
2. 数字が確定している各マスについて、そのマスの横1列にある空きマスから確定している数字のフラグを取り除く
3. 数字が確定している各マスについて、そのマスが属するグループにある空きマスから確定しているのフラグを取り除く
4. 空きマスに残っているフラグが1つしか無い場合、そのマスを残った数字で確定する

これで結構効率良く出来るはずですが、解けないパターンがあることにも注意して下さい。

```
972 538 164
861 749 235
345 AB6 789

789 CD3 456
126 954 378
453 867 912

214 675 893
697 382 541
538 491 627
```

これは2つの正解があります。
A=1, B=2, C=2, D=1
と
A=2, B=1, C=1, D=2
です。

無限ループのようになり、とおっしゃっているのはもしかしたら絶対解けない問題を解いているのかもしれません。
9×9では最初にわかっている数字が6つ以下だと解けない、と聞いたこともあります。

終了条件が難しいと思います。

Comment: ステップの解説部分を番号付きリストで書き換えました。